# D and SDL - functions undefined

Tags: compiler-errors, sdl, d, undefined-symbol

I've got this very simple D program (pk.d):

```
import std.stdio;
import SDL;

int main(string[] args) {
    writefln("Hello world");
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0) {
        writefln("Unable to init SDL");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've got a very straightforward make script (I'm on Windows here, but the Windows D compiler comes packaged with a bash interpreter):

```
DMD=dmd
DFLAGS=-I./lib/SDL 

$(DMD) pk $(DFLAGS)
pk
```

**But when I build it, I get `Error 42: Symbol Undefined _SDL_Init`**

It managed to import SDL alright, and it finds SDL_INIT_VIDEO just fine. I went ahead and checked in SDL.d and found that there was a definition for SDL_Init: `int SDL_Init(Uint32 flags);`. I can't figure this out. This is the first non-STL library that I've imported with D, so hopefully my mistake is obvious, can anyone see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to link with the SDL library. If you have one in the right format, simply pass it to the compiler along with your source files. Alternatively, you can add something like `pragma(lib, "SDL.lib")` to your program.

Comment: FWIW: "Symbol Undefined" and modified names (note the added leading '_') are generally an indication of errors at the link phase and most of the time that amounts to forgetting to add something for linking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need also D bindings for SDL library.

```
import std.stdio;
import sdl;

int main(string[] args)
{
    SDL_Surface * screen;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 24, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen.clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB(screen.format, 
                                                       0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
    SDL_Flip(screen);

    SDL_Delay(6000);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my sample test program. First of all I downloaded [SDL development libraries for VC6](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-devel-1.2.14-VC6.zip)

Than you need to convert library files to OMF format. I preferred *coff2omf* tool which ships with [Borland C++ Compiler](http://forms.embarcadero.com/forms/BCC32CompilerDownload) because it is free. DigitalMars has a tool with same name but it isn't free. Which doesn't make sense to me.

**coff2omf.exe SDL.lib SDL2.lib**

And than I compiled and linked like that:

**dmd -c test.d sdl.d**

**link test.obj sdl.obj SDL2.lib**

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you need D bindings for SDL library you may download from [here](https://github.com/erdemoncel/oyun/). File name is *sdl.d* but not complete yet.